# derivative of many roots

Tags: calculus, derivatives

if $$ y=\frac{(1+2x)^{1/2}.(1+4x)^{1/4}.(1+6x)^{1/6} ... (1+100x)^{1/100}}{(1+3x)^{1/3}.(1+5x)^{1/5}.(1+7x)^{1/7} ... (1+101x)^{1/101}}$$
then find y' at x=0

- Already tried to find a general term that I can differentiate.
- Tried using the Pi notation. But I'm not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you face such monsters, you can be sure of two things

1. No human being would do it using the product and quotient rules for derivatives
2. There must be a trick and, as already said in comments and answers, logarithmic differentiation is more then useful when you face products or quotients.

Using the product notation, the numerator can write $$A=\prod_{k=1}^n (1+2 k x)^{\frac{1}{2 k}}$$ and the denominator $$B=\prod_{k=1}^n (1+(2 k +1)x)^{\frac{1}{2 k+1}}$$ So,  $$y=\frac AB\implies\log(y)=\log(A)-\log(B)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\log(1+2kx)}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\log(1+(2k+1)x)}{2k+1}$$ Now, compute the derivative $$\frac {y'}y=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{1+2kx}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{1+(2k+1)x}$$ Now, you want the value of the derivative for $x=0$; this gives the beautiful $\frac {y'}y=0$ and then $y'=0$ whatever $n$ could be.

Comment: That's the answer I've been trying to find. Thank you!

Comment: @Mario. You are very welcome ! Just remember the trick. Just for fun, apply the method to $y=u(x)\times v(x)$ and $y=\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}$. This will give you the formulae for the derivative of a product and the derivative of a quotient ! Please, do it and tell me if it is funny or not. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

Consider $\ln y=...$

Then $\frac 1y\frac{dy}{dx}=...?$

Comment: In fact, one only has to begin writing a bit of the right-hand side out to see what's going to happen at $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ ; the same is true for the value of $ \ y \ $ itself.  A paper-tiger of a differentiation problem...

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* Compute $\dfrac{y'(x)}{y(x)}$ and use the fact that for
$f = f_1 f_2 ... f_n$ 
$$
 \frac{f'}{f} = \frac{f_1'}{f_1} + \frac{f_2'}{f_2} + ... + \frac{f_n'}{f_n}
$$
(which follows from the product rule for the derivative).

Answer (score 0):

*Note:* This answer is a variation based upon *quotient* and *product rule*.

> Let $y(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ with 
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{50}u_{2k}(x)\qquad\qquad g(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{50}u_{2k+1}(x)
> \end{align*}
>   and 
>   \begin{align*}
> u_k(x)=(1+kx)^{\frac{1}{k}}\qquad 1\leq k\leq 101
> \end{align*}
>
> We observe $u_k(0)=1$ for all $k$ and conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> f(0)=g(0)=1\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We want to calculate $y^\prime(x)$ at $x=0$. So, we consider the quotient rule
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime}(x)=\frac{f^{\prime}(x)g(x)-f(x)g^{\prime}(x)}{g^2(x)}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> The evaluation at $x=0$ gives according to (1) 
>   \begin{align*}
> y^{\prime}(0)=\frac{f^{\prime}(0)\cdot 1- 1\cdot g^{\prime}(0)}{1}=f^{\prime}(0)- g^{\prime}(0)\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> The derivative of $u_k$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> u_k^{\prime}(x)=(1+kx)^{\frac{1}{k}-1}\qquad 1\leq k \leq 101
> \end{align*}
>   and we obtain $u_k^{\prime}(0)=1$.

To calculate $y^{\prime}(0)$ we need $f^{\prime}(x)$ and $g^{\prime}(x)$ evaluated at zero.

> We obtain according to the *[general Leibniz Product Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#A_product_of_more_than_two_factors)*
>   \begin{align*}
> f^{\prime}(x)&=\sum_{j=1}^{50}{u^{\prime}_{2j}(x)}\prod_{{k=1}\atop{k\neq j}}^{50}u_{2k}(x)\\
> g^{\prime}(x)&=\sum_{j=1}^{50}{u^{\prime}_{2j+1}(x)}\prod_{{k=1}\atop{k\neq j}}^{50}u_{2k+1}(x)\\
> \end{align*}
>   and since $u_k(0)=u^{\prime}_k(0)=1$ we conclude $f^{\prime}(0)=g^{\prime}(0)=1$.
>
> We finally obtain according to (3)
>   \begin{align*}
> y^{\prime}(0)=1-1=0
> \end{align*}